# How to remove Encrypted flag when copying a file from a HDD to a USB drive?

Tags: windows-7, usb, encryption, efs

Environment: Windows 7, but applies to other EFS-compatible Windows versions

I have a file that is encrypted using standard Windows EFS encryption. When I copy that file to a USB drive using Total Commander or Explorer, the file stays encrypted at the destination.

Such encrypted file is inaccessible on any other Windows PC where my USB drive gets plugged in. I could import my personal certificates on that PC, but that's about the last thing I would like to do.

I would like the copying process automatically decrypt my file when the file is copied to a removable drive. Is there a way to tell Windows to do that?

A brute-force way to decrypt the file on-the-fly would be to switch to FAT as a file system on my USB drive, but I don't want to do that either.

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: True, using FAT (or exFAT) on the USB drive is a bit crude, but it appears to be the only truly automatic approach currently available.

Answer (score 4):

- **RichCopy** is a Free utility which can **remove encryption *on the fly*** while copying
  files and folders between NTFS formatted drives. (No need of FAT32 partition to decrypt)
- To access the setting, first Check 'Advanced' from
  'View' menu. Then go to 'Copy Options' > Default > File attributes,
  Error Handling > File atttibutes to remove > Encrypted
- Details
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx
- Download https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/microsoft_richcopy.html

Comment: This tool seems to work exactly as advertised - great find!

Comment: _No need of FAT32 partition to decrypt_ - not entirely true, Windows 10 leaves this attribute checked when copying to FAT32 volumes, leaving the file practically unreadable. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-corrupts-files-without-warning-on-sd-cf/e2913a4a-201c-4646-a1b2-661e47419b80

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps with a batch file you could do something like that :

### solution 1

Create a `mycopy.cmd` file (in your `PATH` or in your "user profile directory") with the two lines :

```
COPY %1 %2
CIPHER /D %2
```

With the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys open the execute dialog en type:

```
mycopy file-to-be-copied target-directory
```

### solution 2

If the target directory is always the same you could simplify the file `mycopy.cmd` file as this

```
COPY %1 target-directory
CIPHER /D  target-directory
```

Putting the file in your SendTo directory (`%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`) will provide you a new option *mycopy.cmd* when you make a right clic on a file (in the send to sub menu)

Comment: Just remember that `CIPHER /D` can take a long time. Especially for big files, like a 1.5gb movie. Especially on a USB drive

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the answer from [CmPi](https://superuser.com/users/310329/cmpi):

If you have already copied your folder (e.g. `RootFolder`) and it is encrypted, you can recursively decrypt all the files and sub-folders with the /s option:

```
cipher /d /s:RootFolder
```

Note that you can do it from any PC as long as you exported the certificate and key used to encrypt the files and you imported them from the different PC. Check this link for info on how to transfer EFS certificates:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/share-encrypted-files

Answer (score 1):

The thing that worked for me best, using Windows Command Prompt, is below (and the link where it is described). I had to use this because I had a complex folder structure and lots of files deep in the hierarchy that were encrypted, so it was not feasible to do it one at a time manually.

Encrypt/decrypt folders (recursively in Windows)
https://www.windows-commandline.com/cipher-command-line-encryption-utility/

Encrypt recursively

```
cipher  /A  /E / S:directoryname
```

Decrypt recursively

```
cipher  /A  /D / S:directoryname
```

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy will do it with the `/A-:E` switch (`E` for encryption "attribute") - but not "on the fly": it does it as an (integrated) two-step process: first it does the copy (or move), then it removes the encryption (sort of like doing a copy followed by `cipher /d`.  So its slow.  But I guess you'd spend the time anyway, so if you prefer to do it in one step ...

Answer (score 0):

When copying an encrypted file to a destination that supports EFS, Windows will always carry over the encryption flag, i.e. encrypt the copied file (source: [Win API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). When creating a new file, Windows will use the encryption setting of the folder to determine whether or not to encrypt the file.

Try the following:

- After copying, open the properties of the destination folder.
- **Enable** encryption for it but do not choose to encrypt child objects.
- Apply changes
- **Disable** encryption for the folder and this time choose to decrypt all child objects.

That should do the trick.

Another option is to copy the data to an interim location that does not support encryption (such as a FAT volume), then move it to its destination.

Either way the process may be lengthy, but the only way to decrypt a file on the fly during copying would be to code your own copy utility, bypassing the `CopyFile()` API call but instead reading the source file and creating an identical file at the destination.

Answer (score -2):

To decrypt the file when its copied to your USB media, disable encryption on the USB media. It can still use NTFS (which is what I assume you're using).

Comment: Yes, I use NTFS. Can the EFS encryption really be disabled on per-drive basis? What would be the way to do it? I haven't been able to find any. And btw, the destination folder is not set to have encrypted content (through Properties).

Comment: You're correct. I was thinking of the option that get's checked when a partition is formatted that enables file encryption for the drive. It implies that it can also be disabled (or, more accurately, not enabled). What you *can* do is copy from the encrypted drive/folder to a folder on the USB media that has the encryption flag cleared. This will cause the files to be decrypted on the fly.

Comment: Copying from an encrypted HDD folder to a USB drive folder that does not have the encryption flag set is exactly the case I'm having the issue with. That does not work, the file gets copied to the USB drive's folder without being decrypted.