# exfat sd volumes transfer to pc

Tags: file-transfer, exfat

Camcorders are now being upgraded to handle large sd cards in excess of 32 GB.  I am now seeing cards upto 128 GB.  How does one move these files to a windows pc so as to burn to a BlueRay disk.

Comment: and, why should that be any different from mounting the card on your Windows PC and copying away the files? I can see the concerns on time-to-transfer and compatibility, but is there something else?  Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/257646/why-should-i-use-exfat-over-ntfs-on-removable-media/262304#262304