# ExFAT is good for flash drives only or it also gives benefits on external HDD, instead of NTFS?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, exfat

I have external HDD that around 7 years old and decided to reformat it.
I heard that exFAT is good for flash drives and keeps sectors alive longer, do this applies for external hard drive also?
Any benefits from using exFAT on external HDD, instead of NTFS?
I don't need file and folders access control of NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [these benchmarks](https://www.flexense.com/fat32_exfat_ntfs_usb3_performance_comparison.html) I do not see any benefit of ExFAT over NTFS. NTFS is faster. Of course there are some drawbacks like slightly bigger OS load (especially context switching) but on contemporary system I do not believe will intact overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS is superior to exFAT in many ways.

Only reason it's preferable on flash drives is because it is for example not editing the (file allocation tables) FAT for *contiguous* files and thus causing less wear on NAND cells. This is wear specific to NAND flash drives and so this advantage does not offer any benefits for a spinning drive.

With regards to SSDs which after all are also NAND flash based drives, the main disadvantage vs NTFS is that at least Windows operating systems will not 'TRIM' exFAT file systems while they do NTFS formatted drives. So IF OS supports NTFS TRIM and hardware supports TRIM, you'd want to go NTFS rather than exFAT.

*Again, this NAND flash wear phenomena is not a factor to take into consideration when dealing with spinning disks.*

Answer (score -2):

exFAT is the new generation of FAT32 file system. it's better and larger limitation (16 exabyte file size limitation), it allows you to have bigger allocation and partitions size. so yah, you'll see more improvements on using it. Also, the one thing that I like is that exFAT is readable / writable on all systems, which means if you have Windows and you try to use the external HDD on Mac (or the opposite way) you won't have to reformat the drive so the OS can give you a full access on it !.

exFAT will give you better access control than the NTFS, better performance than the other FAT and NTFS systems. Best solution for external storage especially for flash-based system.

Read More about exFAT
[`Source 1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT)
[`Source 2`](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2801/exfat_versus_fat32_versus_ntfs/)
[`Source 3`](http://lifehacker.com/5927185/use-the-exfat-file-system-and-never-format-your-external-drive-again)
[`Source 4`](https://superuser.com/questions/257646/why-should-i-use-exfat-over-ntfs-on-removable-media)

Would I recommend it for you ? Defenately **YES**.

Comment: -1. Please provide actual sources for all these claims. I very much doubt that ExFAT is faster or has better access control than NTFS.

Comment: Sure, I added the sources to the original post above, you can read more about it.

Comment: Still, nothing about ACLs and the like. While the filesystem might support it, Windows doesn’t. Performance improvement claims are mostly based on theory. I haven’t seen any benchmark supporting them. exFAT is good for interoperability *with OS X*. That’s it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that exFAT support under linux is spotty at best. Ironically, NTFS is more widely supported, if only because it has been around a lot longer.