# Automatically remove encryption when copying to removable device

Tags: windows, filesystems, encryption, file-permissions, file-attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Encrypted flag when copying a file from a HDD to a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/188119/how-to-remove-encrypted-flag-when-copying-a-file-from-a-hdd-to-a-usb-drive)

Windows OS (8 64-bit).

This question has already popped up in [How to remove Encrypted flag when copying a file from a HDD to a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/188119/how-to-remove-encrypted-flag-when-copying-a-file-from-a-hdd-to-a-usb-drive)

with no answer... maybe now there is a way.

So, we have encrypted (green) file on the hdd. How can we copy this file to a removable drive (flash for instance), so that the file will be decrypted i.e. accessible on another systems without the certificate.

Assuming we don't have to right click the file/folder and manually clear the encryption flag..

The problem is, that if some files are encrypted and some are not, the containing folder won't necessarily be showed as encrypted, so even simple right-click flag-removal way won't work.

Let's try to figure this out!

My first proposition is to look up the command line tool to create a batch, and check if only and exactly encrypted file will be decrypted. I use the work-PC as a source and a private-External Drive as a target.

Answer (score 0):

If USB drive is formatted as FAT32, then there's no encryption support (EFS is feature of NTFS). So, file is just decrypted.